# Ask About WCF Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight

I changed the name of the namespace in the interface and the wcf service class, now when I add this service to my project, I encounter this error:

```
There was an error downloading 
'http://localhost:23724/DataAccess/Customer.svc/$metadata'.
The request failed with the error message:
--
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
     <title>The type 'CoffeShop.Web.Business.Customer', provided as the 
 Service attribute value in the ServiceHost directive, or provided in the 
configuration element 
system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/serviceActivations could not be 
found.</title>
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
      <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
   
    </system.web>

    <system.serviceModel>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="">
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="false"
            multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
    </system.serviceModel>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="myDB" connectionString="Data Source=HAJI\HAJISQL;Initial Catalog=CoffeShop;Integrated Security=True"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  
</configuration>
```

my webconfig.
please helpe about this.

```html
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IProduct" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                    maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
                    <security mode="None" />
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
          
            <endpoint address="../DataAccess/Product.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IProduct" contract="ProductService.IProduct"
                name="BasicHttpBinding_IProduct" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

ServiceReferences.ClientConfig  shared.
please help me about this.

Comment: Share the web config.

Comment: @GaganDeep shared it

Comment: I mean the service config buddy.

Comment: @GaganDeep  service Config is not available because wcf service has been added to the project

Comment: I didn't get you, isn't WCF service a seperate project and your website a different one???

Comment: no. my project is a silverlight project and the WCF Service added to myproject.web @GaganDeep

Comment: @GaganDeep but "ServiceReferences.ClientConfig" is available.

Comment: Actually there would be endpoint defined in the config file of the WCF services. Was it working earlier??

Comment: @GaganDeep Yes, it certainly worked

Comment: @GaganDeep ServiceReferences.ClientConfig shared

Comment: "changed the name of the namespace" - a C# namespace or an xmlns ?

Comment: Post the contents of the .svc file, and the outline of the C# Interface and Implementation classes. Including their full namespaces.

Comment: @bommelding a C# namespace

Comment: @bommelding is right. you need to check if the svc file has the fully qualified name of the class. one more thing , could you try and place your endpoint in a single line in web config file. i have seen it not work when placed in multiple lines.

Comment: To open a svc file, right-click and select Open With. Or go around VS and use Notepad. Without it this question is dead.